# when declaring an object how do you specify the no name if it's ambigous

Tags: c++, class, variables, namespaces

I have an ambigous variable delcaration, e.g.:

```
Class myClass;


blah.h : error C2872: 'Class ' : ambiguous symbol
    could be 'foo.h(30) : Class '
    or 'foo2.h(106) : MyNamespace::Class '
```

How do I specifically declare the variable myClass to be of the former class declared in foo.h with no namespace?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the fully qualified class name which always starts with ::

```
::Class myClass;
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you didn't use

```
using namespace myNamespace;
```

but qualified stuff you take from that namespace instead

Comment: +1, or at least use it locally or `using myNamespace::someSpecificFeature`.

Comment: +1 even though I occasionally use `using namespace` until such a conflict occurs – at which point I switch.

Answer (score 1):

::Class means no namespace at all.

Comment: More precisely it means Class from the global namespace. The empty name before the scope resolution operator :: is the name of the global namespace.